# Remove not exists attribute in typescript interface

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have some trouble in using spread operator.
when using spread operator, unexpected attribute exists in created object.
Can I filter only defined attribute or remove undefined attribute?

```
    type test = { id: string }
    const dump = { id: 'id', name: 'name' };
    const testResult: test = { ...dump };
    // wanted result { id: 'id' }
    console.log('test', testResult); // test { id: 'id', name: 'name' }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is not with respect to typescript alone here. Typescript is quite liberal in checking types. In the sense

```
interface IFoo {}
interface IBar {
name: string
}

// No error will be thrown
const foo: IFoo = { name: 'sam' };
const bar: IBar = { name: 'sam' };

// following line will throw error. As IBar expects the property name.
const justFoo: IBar = { greet: 'hello' };
```

Here `foo` can be used as a variable of one of types `IFoo` or `IBar`. Either will work. But it's not true in case of `justFoo`, it can only be IFoo.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it:

```
type test = { id: string }
  const dump = { id: 'id', name: 'name' };
  const testResult: test = {id:dump.id}
```